# Symfony create User manually with Friends Of Symfony

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

So I'm using this bundle for the Users: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle

This works perfect and on my local machine (where I develop) every thing works fine. I created an Admin User over the CLI interface the bundle provides.

Unfortunately the hoster where my client is doesn't allow MySQL access from Command Line. So I'm looking for a was to create a admin user without CLI. I have full access to the code with FTP and I can access the DB with PHPmySQL.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest way without having to bring databases to your local environment and back: on your local environment, run `php app/console fos:user:create -vvv`. This runs debug verbose mode so the `INSERT` query is spewed out:

```
$ php app/console fos:user:create -vvv
[2014-12-04 15:49:45] event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
Please choose a username:test
Please choose an email:test@test.com
Please choose a password:test
[2014-12-04 15:49:55] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2014-12-04 15:49:55] doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO fos_user_user (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, locked, expired, expires_at, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, credentials_expired, credentials_expire_at, created_at, updated_at, date_of_birth, firstname, lastname, website, biography, gender, locale, timezone, phone, facebook_uid, facebook_name, facebook_data, twitter_uid, twitter_name, twitter_data, gplus_uid, gplus_name, gplus_data, token, two_step_code) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) {"1":"test","2":"test","3":"test@test.com","4":"test@test.com","5":true,"6":"caah6vuazqosss48w8cwsssog080k8k","7":"9frgaqCv4zJQky6YUTLR5UzebY [...]","8":null,"9":false,"10":false,"11":null,"12":null,"13":null,"14":[],"15":false,"16":null,"17":"2014-12-04 15:49:55","18":"2014-12-04 15:49:55","19":null,"20":null,"21":null,"22":null,"23":null,"24":"u","25":null,"26":null,"27":null,"28":null,"29":null,"30":null,"31":null,"32":null,"33":null,"34":null,"35":null,"36":null,"37":null,"38":null} []
[2014-12-04 15:49:55] doctrine.DEBUG: "COMMIT" [] []
Created user test
```

All you really need from that long debug `INSERT` output are the values for `salt`, `roles`, and `password` - you can do the rest from your favourite MySQL client with little issue. If your host isn't providing you with a way to access your MySQL database, you can [install PHPMyAdmin somewhere in your `web/` folder](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) and gain access through there. I probably wouldn't leave it installed though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a controller also:

*app/config/routing.yml*:

```
create_admin_user:
    pattern: adminuser/create
    defaults: {_controller: ACMEDemoBundle:Any:createAdmin}
```

*src/ACME/DemoBundle/Controller/AnyController.php*

```
<?php
namespace ACME\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class AnyController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Creates admin user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function createAdminAction()
    {
        $userManipulator = $this->get('fos_user.util.user_manipulator');
        $adminPassword = "supersecret";
        $adminUsername = "superadmin";
        $adminEmail = "super@admin.com";
        $isActive = true;
        $isSuperAdmin = true;        
        $userManipulator->create($adminUsername, $adminPassword, $adminEmail, $isActive, $isSuperAdmin);

        return new Response();
    }
}
```

And invoke the url `http://yourhost:<port>/adminuser/create`

Answer (score 0):

You could export the 'User' and 'UserGroup' tables locally and import them on your hosters environment via phpMyAdmin.

But sure to make a backup of your database before.

Comment: I actually tried that but it didn't work (allthough I had the same secret in the parameter file)